# Newton's Method Calling Functions C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am to write a function that attempts to find the zero of a function using Newton's Method.

I have my function and derivative of x^7-1000

```
double function(double x) {
    return pow(x, 7) - 1000;    
}
double derivative(double x) {
    return 7 * pow(x, 6);
}
```

I also have Newton's function

```
using fx = double(*)(double);

double newtons( fx f, fx df, double x0, double e ) 
{
    double x1{};
    while( true ) {
        x1 = x0 - f( x0 ) / df( x0 );

        if( std::abs( x1 - x0 ) <= e ) break;

        x0 = x1;
    }

    return x1;
}
```

How do I call the functions to my int main?

Comment: What part is giving you problems? I'm assuming you understand how to call a function. Do you know how to write a main?

Comment: What happens when `df( x0)` returns 0 or close to zero?  Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_functions.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << newtons(function, derivative, 10.5, 1.0e-5) << std::endl;
}
```

Note (tx @martinbonner): using templates and the stl, you can make it even more generic: using lambda expressions, existing functions, ... anything 'invokeable'.

```
template<typename F>
double newtons(F f, F df, double x0, double e) {
   ... // same as your code
}

// usage:
auto x = newtons(std::sin, std::cos, 0.5, 1e-5);
auto x2 = newtons(
   [](double d){ return d*d + 2*d - 1; },
   [](double d){ return 2*d + 2; },
   0,
   1.0e-5);
```

Comment: You also need `#include "newtons.h"`.

Comment: It is apparent that he assumed the functions to reside in the header file "my_functions.h"

Comment: Might be nice to mention that you can also call it as `newtons( [](double x){return std::pow(x, 7.) - 1000;},
                          [](double x){return 7.* std::pow(x,6.);},
                          10.5, 1E-5)
` - which is a lot more readable with a few line breaks!

Comment: Yeah I was _almost_ adding that.  Pressed cancel though :).  Will add it even so.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially as follows (assuming everything is in scope)

```
int main() {
    std::cout << newtons(function, derivative, 
                         10.5 /* Start point */, 0.00001 /* Error delta */);
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://ideone.com/apLSuq)</kbd>